# How to split a list with respect to its nested sublists?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, permutation

I have a problem with the following task: having some nested list

```
list = {{k6},{k1,k3,k5},{k7}}
```

I would like to replace all sublists by their permutations and then split original list w.r.t. these permutations. So I started with permutations

```
list1 = {{{k6}},{{k1,k3,k5},{k1,k5,k3},{k3,k1,k5},{k3,k5,k1},{k5,k1,k3},{k5,k3,k1}},{{k7}}}
```

but I got stuck at this point - how to split this list w.r.t. sublists, i.e. to get:

```
list2 = {{{{k6}},{{k1,k3,k5}},{{k7}}},{{{k6}},{{k1,k5,k3}},{{k7}}},...}
```

Then I would like also to obtain a list of the form

```
{{k6,k1,k3,k5,k7},{k6,k1,k5,k3,k7},...}
```

Perhaps there is a simpler method to do this?

Obviously, if e.g.

```
list = {{k6},{k1,k3},{k2,k5},{k7}}
```

then the splitting should give list with all combinations of permutations of `{k1,k3}` and `{k2,k5}` taken into account preserving original order.

Comment: If I understood Your problem correctly `Flatten[]` with level consideration should solve it.

Comment: @Kuba The number of sublists is variable. I think yours is the only solution that works under this condition so far.

Comment: @belisarius ok, that was my guess

Answer (score 8):

```
list = {{k6}, {k1, k3, k5}, {k7}};

Flatten /@ Tuples[Permutations /@ list]
```

> ```
> {{k6, k1, k3, k5, k7}, {k6, k1, k5, k3, k7}, {k6, k3, k1, k5, k7}, 
>   {k6, k3, k5, k1, k7}, {k6, k5, k1, k3, k7}, {k6, k5, k3, k1, k7}}
> ```

Comment: that's a wonderful solution @Kuba!

Answer (score 5):

[`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html?q=SlotSequence&lang=en)  helps providing an elegant and terse style of *Mathematica* programming:

```
Outer[ ## &, ## & @@ list1, 1]
```

> ```
> {{{{k6}, {k1, k3, k5}, {k7}}, {{k6}, {k1, k5, k3}, {k7}}, 
>   {{k6}, {k3, k1, k5}, {k7}}, {{k6}, {k3, k5, k1}, {k7}}, 
>   {{k6}, {k5, k1, k3}, {k7}}, {{k6}, {k5, k3, k1}, {k7}}}}
> ```

or satisfying another expectation in the question:

```
Apply[ ## &, %, {3}][[1]]
```

> ```
> {{k6, k1, k3, k5, k7}, {k6, k1, k5, k3, k7}, {k6, k3, k1, k5, k7}, 
>  {k6, k3, k5, k1, k7}, {k6, k5, k1, k3, k7}, {k6, k5, k3, k1, k7}}
> ```

Comment: Nice fix.... +1

Answer (score 4):

A rule based approach:

```
l = {{k6}, {k1, k3, k5}, {k7}}
l1 = Permutations /@ l
l2 = ReplaceList[l1, {{___, a_, ___}, {___, b_, ___}, {___, c_, ___}} -> {a, b, c}]
(*
 {{{k6}, {k1, k3, k5}, {k7}}, 
  {{k6}, {k1, k5, k3}, {k7}}, 
  {{k6}, {k3, k1, k5}, {k7}}, 
  {{k6}, {k3, k5, k1}, {k7}}, 
  {{k6}, {k5, k1, k3}, {k7}}, 
  {{k6}, {k5, k3, k1}, {k7}}}
*)
```

You can do

```
 Flatten /@l2
```

If you want to get flattened lists as the result

**Edit**

The following works for  variable number of lists. Perhaps not elegant, but I wanted to stick with `ReplaceList[]`:

```
l = {{k6}, {k1, k3, k5}, {k7}}
l1 = Permutations /@ l
l2 = ReplaceList[l1, Array[ToExpression["{___,x" <> ToString[#] <> "_,___}"] &, Length@l] -> 
                     Array[ToExpression["x" <> ToString[#]] &, Length@l]]
```

Or shorter (by @PinguinDirk)

```
ReplaceList[l1, With[{vars = (Unique["x"] & /@ Range[Length@l1])}, 
                     {___, Pattern[#, Blank[]], ___} & /@ vars -> vars]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = Permutations[#] & /@ list;
Flatten[{{First[list1] /. List -> Sequence, # /. List -> Sequence, 
     Last[list1] /. List -> Sequence}} & /@ list1[[2 ;; -2]][[1]], 1]
```

> {{k6, k1, k3, k5, k7}, {k6, k1, k5, k3, k7}, {k6, k3, k1, k5, 
>     k7}, {k6, k3, k5, k1, k7}, {k6, k5, k1, k3, k7}, {k6, k5, k3, k1, 
>     k7}}